# Copy files from assets folder to apps private /data/data folder and chmod?

Tags: android

I have a file named flash_image in my apps asset folder.

I am wanting to copy this to my apps private data folder, and make it executable (my app will be running with root permissions, if this helps).

So, I want the file to be located at `/data/data/com.liamwli.flash/flash_image` and have that file executable.

I have tried many methods I found online, but I cannot get it to work.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to save some data in /data folder, so you really want to save the data in devices internal memory. Check this out: [Android Developers Storage Options Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). Also try changing mode to Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE. I hope this will lead you in some way.